# Upload new Application to App Store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my first app to App Store. I have completed all the required steps to iTunes Connect and the status of me app is "Waiting For Upload".

I believe that the next step is to use Application Loader to load the binaries file. Am I right?

I launch Application Loader and I choose "Delivery Your App", then from the combo I choose my application and "Next".

In the next screen "Deliver Your App" there is a button called "Choose..." but I cannot understand what I have to choose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choose the compressed binary for your app from your disk to upload.

If you are following the instructions from Apple Developer Support Center, you would've done the process of clicking on the app from "Products" tab in Xcode to reveal the binary for your app in "Finder." You would've compressed the app while in "Finder." App Loader is asking you for this compressed binary.

Adding this update:
The new Xcode (version 4 and higher) now integrates Apploader much better. You can do the following steps:
1. Plug-in an iOS device that have been provisioned for development
2. Select the device (instead of one of the simulators) as the build target
3. From Xcode, select Product -> Archive to build and archive your product (Xcode will archive your product and launch the Organizer window to allow you to distribute your product
4. While your archive is selected, click on "Distribute" button on the Organizer window to start the dialogue to send your binary up to Apple.

Comment: Thanks Sunny. You really helped me...!

Comment: I am glad to help. I presume you can vote for the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: This process is outlined in this documentation: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Comment: Jared, Apple's documentations are, sometimes, as clear as mud. The question wasn't about where to find the documentation but what was meant by statements in the documentation. It was a request for clarification.

Comment: the only thing I was missing that it should be compressed